# Need help in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new into shell scripting and learning it for past 2 month. I need your help in tuning or providing any other solution either in sed or AWK for the below question.

"write a script to input the filename and display the content of file in such a manner that each line has only 10 characters.If line in a file exceeds 10 characters then display the rest of the line in next line."

I have written the below script and worked fine. But it took 2 hours for me to write it..(certainly not acceptable. Problem is i know the shell commands very well but still have not mastered the skills to put them into shell scripts :-( . Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo "USAGE: $0 $1"
exit 99;
fi

VAR1=$(echo "$1" | wc -c)

cat "$1" | while read line
        do
           [ $VAR1 -gt 10 ] && echo "$line" || echo "$line"|tr " " "\n"
        done
```

Comment: It is good that you are reporting a usage.  However, since there is no `$1`, the user won't know what they're supposed to type.  It looks like the echo should be: `echo "Usage: $0 filename" >&2`, where `Usage` is normally spelled in mixed case, and the output for an error message should go to standard error rather than standard output.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled. The value in `$VAR1` is the number of characters in the file name.  The code in the body of the loop is inscrutable (use a regular `if/then/else`; if you want to write one-liners, go and learn APL).  If the file name is longer than 10 characters, you echo the line unchanged; otherwise, you echo the line replacing blanks with newlines.  I'm not sure that meets the specification very closely.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/........../&\n/g' file.txt
```

Using `grep`

```
grep -oE '.{1,10}' file.txt
```

Using `dd`

```
cat file.txt | dd cbs=10 conv=unblock 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks so much hashbrown. this is awesome. I also read the sed manual and got another solution  - sed -r 's/^.{10}/&\n/g' filename.txt. It's working fine in Linux, not sure whether it will work in any other unix flavour.

Comment: @krishnamurti yes, this should work in most new versions of `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`?

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i % 10 == 0) printf "%s\n", $i ; else if (i == NF) print "\n" ; else printf "%s", $i} ' inputs.txt
```

This works, but I have a feeling that this is not the most optimal way of using awk :-P

Comment: I am getting such a great answers. thanks. can you please explain this f=part for me: if (i % 10 == 0) printf "%s\n", $i ; else if (i == NF) print "\n" ; else printf "%s", $i}. From what i understood, it will check if there are any charaters at place 10 then print the newline else if it is equal to the number of fields then ??(did not understood) else just print the line.

Comment: +1. I start with `BEGIN {FS=""}` -- this means each character will count as one character (even spaces).  

With regards to the for loop; `i` will represent character count and `$i` will represent the character.  

`if (i % 10 == 0) printf "%s\n", $i` -- if count divided by 10 has remainder 0 (i.e. every tenth character), print the character plus a new line.  

`else if (i == NF) print "\n"` -- if count is the last character of the line, print a newline.  

`else printf "%s", $i}` -- for everything else (i.e. not the tenth character or end of line), print the character.